# How to switch "context area type" via Pie command? Object/Edit<>Nodes<>UVImage

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

In a Pie menu instead of switching just edit/object mode I would also like to swap out the content of the display like from 3D view switch to node editor for the selected object. But I have a hard time figuring out how to write this.

I went to the API page to see if many I can get some clues from there.
**https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.context.html?highlight=context.area#bpy.context.area**

If I switch the modes the console reads this out:

```
bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
bpy.context.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
bpy.context.area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
```

To define a edit/object mode switch I 3D view I know you can do it this way:

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

pie.operator("object.editmode_toggle", text="Edit/Object", icon='OBJECT_DATAMODE')
```

So I tried this but obviously it odes not work

```
pie.operator("context.area").type='IMAGE_EDITOR'
```

With the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Modeling Toolbox Pie Beta.py", line 654, in draw

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wazou wrote a good viewport/editor switch pie a while back and I've been modifying it lately. You can find it on github in [addons_extern](https://github.com/meta-androcto/blenderpython/blob/master/scripts/addons_extern/Viewport_Pie_menu.py). I don't completely understand it, but I believe it's close to what you're asking for. You could probably borrow some parts of the code for your own pie.

Comment: I studied it but to my knowledge it only switches between edit/object/sculpt mode and not swaping out the 3D view with the node or image editor module.

Comment: We're looking at different scripts, because viewport_pie_menu.py allows you to change editors in a window. Press shift-space over any editor other than the console and it gives you options to switch between editors. Up is 3D view, left is a submenu of image editors, etc.

Comment: OPS - same name different thing. Thank you for this! The example is perfect to learn from!

Answer (score 4):

There are already shortcuts defined to switch areas.

```
UserPreferences -> Input -> Window
```

If you browse these shortcuts you will find `Context Set Enum`, which uses the generic [`wm.context_set_enum`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=wm#bpy.ops.wm.context_set_enum) operator. The keys are <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F1-F12</kbd>

So you can copy the arguments:

```
op_props = pie.operator("wm.context_enum_set")
op_props.data_path = "area.type"
op_props.value = "VIEW_3D"
```

See [Area.type](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.Area.html?highlight=area.type#bpy.types.Area.type) for the available options

Further you might also try [wm.context_pie_enum](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=enum#bpy.ops.wm.context_pie_enum) to automatically layout all enum items in a pie menu.

Just define a shortcut and type `area.type` in the `data_path` field.

---

#### Note

You can find a listing of all context attributes [here](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.context.html)

Comment: Tested context_pie_enum and it seems to be buggy :/ - multiple areas are assigned to the same direction.